# Function - delete 3 lasts elements

Tags: php

Function don't work

```
$k = array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eigth','nine');


    function del_el_3($array){
        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
            unset($array[array_pop($array)]);
        }
    }


    del_el_3($k);


    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($k);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "function don't work". That isn't a lot of information for us to try to help.

Comment: As my understanding you want to remove last 3 elements from given array, Did you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000108/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-array-pop-the-last-n-elements-in-an-array

Comment: Please add more information .. like what do you want your function to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using $i inside the for loop to get the index of the value

Also, you are unsetting as well as popping, both do the same sort of thing.

So you should only need to do this:

```php
function del_el_3($array){
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
```

Or this:

```php
function del_el_3($array){
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        array_pop($array);
        print_r($a);
    }
}
```

Which will remove the 3 elements, and you can also print them if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

`array_pop` is the correct function to use however I'm unsure why you are nesting it. You can either call `$array = array_pop($array);` 3 times or I would suggest looking at [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000108/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-array-pop-the-last-n-elements-in-an-array) for a neater solution.